# Big-Theta extension of Brent's Theorem?

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, asymptotics

Is there an extension or translation of Brent's theorem into asymptotics aside from big-$O$?

Brent's Theorem: [source](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~prins/Classes/633/Handouts/pram.pdf)

Running time of a parallel algorithm with $p$ processors (say, $f(n,p)$), $W(n)$ Work complexity, and $S(n)$ Step complexity takes $\leq \frac{W(n)}{p} + S(n)$ time.  The $\leq$ lets me use $O$ directly, but not $\Omega$.  If it's also true, I'd be able to say something like:

$f(n,p) \in \frac{\Theta(W(n))}{p} + \Theta(S(n))$

It seems like it is true.  Is it?  I'd love to have a reference.

Comment: You're asking for a lower bound on the conversion of an algorithm into a parallel algorithm ? that is likely to be hard.

Comment: The algorithm shouldn't need to be converted.  I just want to know whether Big-Theta holds.